# Check Session Variables in each HTTP Request with .NET

Tags: .net, session, authentication

Is there a way in .NET to check the existence of certain Session variables upon each HTTP request, without having to include this check in each page's code behind?

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach would be to create a base page class that all your pages inherit from, and do the check there.

In IIS 7.5 you can setup custom [Request Filter](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering) rules.

Comment: Only problem w/ the base page class is that I am using a lot of AJAX and this check wouldn't be included automatically. The IIS Request Filter is a really good suggestion. They don't outright explain how to check for session variables but I may be able to find it.

Comment: There are lots of ways to approach this - you could also implement an HTTP Handler to check ALL incoming requests before routing them to your page.